# Main Backbone view not showing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, require

I am trying to make a simple Backbone web app.  I am using require to manage all of my dependencies.  My html is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/todos.css">
    <title>Clinical Auth</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/require-2.1.1.js" data-main="js/app"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My app.js is just a router that calls my application.view.js:

```
require([
    'backbone',
    'views/application.view'
  ], function(Backbone, app) {
  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "main"
    },

    main: function(){
      var appView = new app();
      appView.render();
    }
  });

  var router = new Router();
  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

As you can see I start my app in the route title `main`.  My application.view.js is also very simple.

```
define(function(require) {
  "use strict";

   var Backbone = require('backbone');
   var $  = require('jquery');
   var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:  $('#container'),
    render: function() {
      $(this.el).append("<div>hello world</div>");
      return this;
    }
  });

  return AppView;
});
```

Also, here is my require.config file:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "./js/",
  paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.8.2',
    underscore: 'lib/underscore-1.4.2',
    backbone: 'lib/backbone-0.9.2',
    'backbone.localStorage': 'lib/backbone.localStorage'
  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'backbone.localStorage': {
      deps: ['backbone'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    }
  }
});
```

When I set a breakpoint in my main route, I can see that the `container` is being manipulated, but it is never making it to my screen.  What am I doing wrong?  I know that this will be something simple, but I am pulling my hair out.

Comment: What about passing in the `el` to Your AppView, something like `var app = new app({el: $('#container')})`.

Comment: Probably a timing issue, why not use `el: '#container'` instead?

Comment: Works fine with `require` stripped out http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/VLf65/

Comment: Like `mu` said I changed it to `el: '#container'`, because that is the right thing to do.  I also tried `Jack`'s idea, but I still get the same result.

Comment: There is nothing complicated in the code that you have written which should prevent the View from rendering . Do you see any errors in the console. Also post the `require.config` file if possible

Comment: I have no errors, so if there is one, it is failing silently. The config file is now posted above.

Comment: The config looks file.. Try putting a debug point inside render and check what `this.el` points to

Comment: I have already done that.  It points to the container.  I see the `hello world` show up in the console, but it just never makes it to the screen.

Comment: Since the problem is just some other CSS that was setting the contain to `display:none` this question probably should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with this code.  I had a css file that set the `container` elements display property to `none`.  Sorry to waste everyones time.